# In Android XML is there a touch input?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Is it possible to create a touch draw area to take signatures in a form?

I am working on an application to collect information though a form and would like to collect signatures by letting users of the app draw a signature on the screen. How would I do this for android. Preferably I would like the "signature" stored as a image to save somewhere.

Does anyone have any idea?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Google's API example of Fingerpaint -- the full app is included in the samples -- but the code to the main Java file is [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html).

Basically, make some small section of the view a canvas control (like in finger paint) and then when the user presses done, save the `Canvas` as an image (using the `Bitmmap` object attached to the `Canvas`.)

You may want to turn rotation off for this particular view, otherwise the signature will get cleared when you rotate the image -- unless you implement some way of rotating it.